# package 'caption' not adjusting captions from the 'listing' environment in 'minted'

Tags: tables, floats, captions, listings, minted

It appears that package `caption` is not able to adjust the captions in listings from `minted`. In the example below, the captions for `figure` and `table` environments are affected by `\captionsetup` but captions for the `listing` environment are not:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{minted}

\graphicspath{{./images/}}

\setmonofont{Courier New}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85, 0.85, 0.85}
\setmintedinline{bgcolor=bg}
\setminted{bgcolor=bg, linenos}
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\small\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=40pt}
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=40pt}
\captionsetup[listing]{skip=40pt}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{listing}[H]
        \begin{minted}[gobble=12]{python}
            def f(x):
                return x**2
            
            if __name__=="__main__":
                x = 3
                y = f(x)
                print(y)
        \end{minted}
        \caption{A python code block}
        \label{lst:python-code-block}\end{listing}

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \label{fig:banana}
        \includegraphics[scale=1.0]{banana.jpg}
        \caption{my-caption}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{table}[h]
        \caption{Simple table caption}
        \label{tab:my-simple-table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Right &
            Left &
            Center &
            Default \\
            \hline\hline
            12 &
            12 &
            12 &
            12 \\
            \hline
            123 &
            123 &
            123 &
            123 \\
            \hline
            1 &
            1 &
            1 &
            1 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way I can use the `caption` package to adjust the captions for the `listing` environments as well? If not how can I adjust the caption spacing for `minted` `listing` environments?

Answer (score 1):

Load the package `minted` with the key `newfloat` :

```
\usepackage[newfloat=true]{minted}
```

The new type of float called `listing` will be created with the package `newfloat` (more modern).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage[newfloat=true]{minted}

\graphicspath{{./images/}}

\setmonofont{Courier New}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85, 0.85, 0.85}
\setmintedinline{bgcolor=bg}
\setminted{bgcolor=bg, linenos}
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\small\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=40pt}
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=40pt}
\captionsetup[listing]{skip=40pt}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{listing}
        \begin{minted}[gobble=12]{python}
            def f(x):
                return x**2
            
            if __name__=="__main__":
                x = 3
                y = f(x)
                print(y)
        \end{minted}
        \caption{A python code block}
        \label{lst:python-code-block}\end{listing}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \label{fig:banana}
        \includegraphics[scale=1.0]{banana.jpg}
        \caption{my-caption}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{table}
        \caption{Simple table caption}
        \label{tab:my-simple-table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Right &
            Left &
            Center &
            Default \\
            \hline\hline
            12 &
            12 &
            12 &
            12 \\
            \hline
            123 &
            123 &
            123 &
            123 \\
            \hline
            1 &
            1 &
            1 &
            1 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]